# What is a word for "services not provided" or "Goods paid for not delivered"?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, synonyms, legalese

What is a word for "services not provided" or "Goods paid for not delivered"?
For example: The "scam" is a word for a dishonest scheme. The word "fraud" is a word for wrongful or criminal deception intended to result in financial or personal gain.

Similarly I was wondering if there is any legal or technical term for not getting what you paid for. A scenario for this would be you always buy from Amazon.com, but this time you paid for a product but it was never delivered, Or you left you car at the carwash for a day but it was returned to you without being washed even though you paid them.

Thanks, Again.

Answer (score 1):

It's a "failure to deliver" which, according to [this page](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/breach-of-contract.asp) is a serious "breach of contract". Breach of contract can be more minor but any legal action for failure to deliver would, I think, be taken under breach of contract legislation.

Comment: If you can prove intent, it can be fraud.